# CastleWindsor not working with route in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I have a WebApplication in ASP.NET MVC using the dependency injection with CastleWindsor but when I add a route attribute, the application returns following error "The controller no found".

My ControllerInstaller

```
public class ControllerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                            .BasedOn<IController>()
                            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

I have a following controller:

```
[Route("espetaculos")]
[FrontAuthorize]
public class EventController : Controller
{
    #region DependencyInjection

    private readonly IApplication applicationWeb;
    private readonly IEventBusiness eventBusiness;
    private readonly IShowBusiness showBusiness;
    private readonly ISession sessionWeb;
    private readonly ILog iLog;

    public EventController(IEventBusiness eventBusiness, IShowBusiness showBusiness, IApplication applicationWeb, ISession sessionWeb, ILog iLog)
    {
        this.eventBusiness = eventBusiness;
        this.showBusiness = showBusiness;
        this.applicationWeb = applicationWeb;
        this.sessionWeb = sessionWeb;
        this.iLog = iLog;
    }
```

when I access the route "/espetaculos" here is the error

[image: error]

The Castle expects only the full path of controller?

**Edit**
My RouteConfig class

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

        //routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Plateia.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably a routing issue and is not related to castle-windsor. What controller do you expected to be invoked when you use the "espetaculos" path? Do you have a controller called "espetaculos"?

Comment: Please post your routing configuration.

Comment: What happens when you remove Castle, add a default constructor to the controller and let MVC create your controller? Is the result the same or does that actually work?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Only route config that I have in project is the attribute route.

Comment: @Steven, work normally

Comment: @Malinosqui - so in other words, you haven't called `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in order to register your [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)?

Comment: I update the question with my routesconfig code. @NightOwl888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, you apparently haven't enabled attribute routing in MVC. Without doing so, adding the `[Route]` attribute on your controllers and actions will have no effect.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

        // This line is required in order to scan
        // for [Route] attribute in your controllers
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Plateia.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! its work! but now i have the "MvcApplication.container" null